# Is it necessary to choose predictors for svm or I use all my variables?

Tags: categorical-data, svm, lasso

I have transformed my categorical variables to dummies and I have used the lasso method to decide which variables I choose to do the logistic regression, my question is: for the svm model do I need to use the variables that have come out with the lasso or I can use all of them?